# Условный оператор if на Clojure

Tags: lisp, clojure

Здравствуйте! Ещё в самом начале изучения Clojure. Подскажите пожалуйста.

У меня есть clojure-проект. Я использую шаблонизатор hiccup и стили Bootstrap. Всё работает. Но вот только не понимаю как работают условные операторы в моём случае.

Вот мой код:

Файл **project.clj:**

```
(defproject yupppie "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "ссылка (ссылка словом потому что не позволяет репутация вставлять)"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "ссылка"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
  :ring {:handler yupppie.core/app})
```

**Файл yupppie.core:**

```
(ns yupppie.core
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.params :refer [wrap-params]]
            [clojure.pprint :refer :all]
            [hiccup.core :refer :all]
            [hiccup.page :refer [include-css include-js]]))

(defn home []
  (html
    [:head (include-css "/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
     (include-css "/styles.css")
     (include-css "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons")
     (include-js "/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")]

[:body
      [:div {:class "col-lg-6"}
      [:div {:class "input-group"}
      [:input {:type "text" :class "form-control" :placeholder "How old are you?"}
      [:span {:class "input-group-btn"}
      [:button {:class "btn btn-default" :type=" button"} "Go, baby!"]]]]]]))

                                            ;
(defroutes app
           (route/resources "/")
           (GET "/" [] (home))
           (POST "/saveform" req
                 (with-out-str (clojure.pprint/pprint (:params req)))))
(def apps
  (wrap-params app))
```

Я стал изучать его недавно, так что пока не очень понимаю.

У меня есть простая форма. И при вводе в поле цифры меньше 18 и нажатии на кнопку, нужно сделать так чтобы показывалась одна картинка, а при вводе цифры 18 или больше другая картинка. Вот как мне использовать условный оператор if, чтобы это заработало? Куда вставлять код и что писать?

Comment: Вы отправку значения поля на сервер уже сделали? Не вижу релевантного кода.

Comment: Нет, пока не сделал. Я сейчас локально пробую.

Answer (score 4):

Рассчитываю, что вы разберётесь, как прислать значение в форме. Я предположу, что с этим вы разобрались и в параметрах к запросу прилетает нужное значение.

Предположу, что строка с присланным числом доступна в параметрах под ключом `age` и потому может быть забиндена в Compojure, как:

```clj
(POST "/" [age] ???)
```

#### Там строка. Нам надо число.

Можно не изобретать велосипедов и затянуть функцию `as-int` из [`compojure.coercions`](https://weavejester.github.io/compojure/compojure.coercions.html). Правда, потребуется чуть-чуть изменить описание метода:

```clj
(POST "/" [age :<< as-int] ???)
```

Альтернативы? В них нет необходимости, [реализация `as-int`](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/blob/master/src/compojure/coercions.clj#L4) предельно проста:

```clj
(try
  (Long/parseLong s)
  (catch NumberFormatException _ nil))
```

Не видя её исходников ранее, я попытался написать код преобразования сам. Единственным отличием от `as-int` оказалось использование `Integer/parseInt`. И оно было ошибочным!

#### Теперь считаем, достаточно ли юзер стар, и сообщаем об этом в шаблон

```clj
(let [old-enough? (and (-> age nil? not) ; если число не распарсилось, придёт nil
                       (< 18 age))]
  (функция-шаблончик old-enough?))
```

В шаблончике... ну, просто берёте и вместо одного из узлов DOM кладёте `if`.

```clj
(defn функция-шаблончик [old-enough?]
  (html [:body (if old-enough?
                   "YEAH"
                   "NOPE")]))
```

Примеры, конечно, совершенно примитивные. Но вы же можете их развить, верно? :)

Comment: Спасибо! Развить смогу)

Comment: Ну конечно я только начал его изучать и это для меня не так просто на данном этапе. Но попробую.

Comment: @Piston Если с этим моментом вы разобрались, пометьте ответ, как решение. Вселите в читателей уверенность, что это работает :)

Comment: Нет. Пока не разобрался. Как заработает, помечу) Нужно разобраться.